# Alternative to Apple Lion server Profile Manager

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, osx-lion

First let me say I am a total newbie on iOS but very experienced in other mobile platforms.

I have to deploy a configuration profile to almost one hundred of iPads. For what I understand this can be done:

- Connecting each device to a computer and using iPhone Configuration Utility.
- Serving the profile via a web server (as shown [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/OTASecurity/OTASecurity.html))

I have not material time to code a service to implement the flow between the device and the server. I was looking for available solutions and I found Apple Lion Server has a Profile Manager (which I understand does what I need).

I tried to find some open source and/or free solutions providing this feature (installing the profile in remote devices) but I couldn't find any.

My questions are: Are my above statements true? Is there any already available solution to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

Profile manager is free. You just need to install a trust profile on the iPads.